# google places api - json return correct data and then an exception occurs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, exception, google-places-api

I'm using google places API, 
The json return valid results, In my async methods I'm setting markers per each result, the method ends and all of a sudden i get the following thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS code:2 address:0x9243e8, in the output window i get the following: [71539:c07] -[__NSCFString CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb19dd10

I have no clue how to debug this, or where to look for the problem, all my parameters look good.

thanks

Comment: Can you show your json response and json parsed data????

Comment: the crash is because key value you are accessing is a string and you are giving it as a image. That's why because string odes not have image method it giving you bad excess.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are doing is as a commenter says, treating the returned JSON object as a type it is not. Specifically, from your error, you are treating a string like an image. Generally, JSON doesn't not contain actually images, so when you deserialize it, you will not get images. In the Google Places API, it does not send you images. Instead, it send you URLs to images. You will have to download the images using the URLs you get from the Places API.

Here is some code I use. This method gets the place list from the API based on a `CLLocation` and returns it as a much more easily digested `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects each containing the important met-data pertaining to a place:

```
-(NSArray*)getPlaceListForLocation:(CLLocation*)inLocation {

    NSString* requestStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=%@&location=%f,%f&radius=100&sensor=true",self.googleAPIKey,inLocation.coordinate.latitude,inLocation.coordinate.longitude];

    NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:requestStr];

    NSLog(@"Fetching place data with URL = %@", requestURL);

    NSData* requestData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:requestURL];

    if ( nil != requestData ) {
        NSError* jsonError = nil;

        id resultsObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestData options:0 error:&jsonError];

        if ( nil == resultsObj ) {
            if ( nil != jsonError ) {
                NSLog(@"%@",jsonError.description);
            }

            return nil;
        }

        NSArray* itemList = [resultsObj objectForKey:@"results"];

        if ( nil == itemList || itemList.count == 0) {
            return nil;
        }

        NSMutableArray* placeList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:itemList.count];

        for ( NSDictionary* item in itemList ) {
            NSString* name = [item objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSString* iconURL = [item objectForKey:@"icon"];
            NSString* vicinity = [item objectForKey:@"vicinity"];
            NSDictionary* geometryDict = [item objectForKey:@"geometry"];
            NSDictionary* locationDict = [geometryDict objectForKey:@"location"];

            NSMutableDictionary* itemDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];

            if ( nil != name ) {
                [itemDict setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
            }

            if (nil != iconURL ) {
                [itemDict setObject:iconURL forKey:@"iconurl"];
            }

            if ( nil != vicinity ) {
                [itemDict setObject:vicinity forKey:@"vicinity"];
            }

            if ( nil != locationDict ) {
                NSString* latitudeStr = [locationDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
                NSString* longitudeStr = [locationDict objectForKey:@"lng"];

                double latitude = [latitudeStr doubleValue];
                double longitude = [longitudeStr doubleValue];

                CLLocation* placeLoc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];

                CLLocationDistance distance = [inLocation distanceFromLocation:placeLoc];

                [itemDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:distance] forKey:@"distance"];
            }


            [placeList addObject:itemDict];
        }

        return placeList;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Then I display these in a table view using the returned `NSArray` as the data source. In order to display the icon, I use something like [`MKNetworkImageView`](https://github.com/michaelkamprath/iPhoneMK/tree/master/Views/MKNetworkImageView) in order to fetch the icon based on the URL.